Creating events on a new data from on-prem
My data comes from a device and is written to on-prem windows server. And I want to create events whenever there is new data. First of all, I would like to sync the data to Azure Cloud. If I understand correctly, Azure File Sync can only sync data to Azure File Share, which does not support triggering mechanism with Azure Data Factory, Logic App and so on.
I have read alternative ways like, enabling Diagnostics on File Share which logs file changes and send the logs to EventHub. And create events based on that. Another alternative is to implement a custom ADF pipeline to sync the data from File Share to Blob, which then supports events. And I would like to ask here, what would be the best solution for this?
I would appreciate any recommendations.

Currently, ADF or logic app does not support event trigger for the Azure File share. You can try the below possible workarounds to achieve your requirement.
You can use the Schedule trigger in ADF to trigger the pipeline with certain time intervals. The pipeline should get the files which are created in these time intervals.
Use copy activity Last modified Start Time and End Time to give the intervals.
Give the timings in the schedule trigger. For sample, here I am scheduling the pipeline on 6:30 AM IST every day.

Give the same interval time in the copy activity Start Time and End Time. You can use Date time functions to give the desired interval range. In each pipeline run, the files created in those time ranges will get filtered and copied to your destination.

Also, you can use the same concept in the Function apps as well. Use Timer trigger for this. You can check this SO Answer by @Amey Pimpley.
